# ERC223 Token Fallback Function Usage

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm currently writing the "Trade" smart contract which is similar to "Crowdsale" smart contract. The only function that I want to add is "sell" function. In general Crowdsale smart contract is used for making people buy their token. There is no problem to implement "buy" function because of the `payable`. Not only it can make the Smart Contract can receive the ether but also it is able to make the transaction of particular payable function (i.e. `function buy() payable public {}`).

I need the `Token Fallback function` as ether does so I found the `ERC223` which is improved based on ERC20. I'm wondering if I can use a Token Fallback Function in another Smart Contract. I mean another deployed contract. For instance, let's assume that someone transfer/send my erc20 custom tokens to "Trade" Smart Contract because he/she wants to sell some amount of tokens and get the proportional amount of ether back (using Web3 like this `myContract.methods.transfer()`). After the "Trade" Smart Contract received the token, `Token Fallback Function` in "Trade" Smart Contract is called and executed the "Sell" function in that Contract. Is that make sense?

The problem is how can I implement this?

```
function transfer(address _to, uint _value, bytes _data) public {
    require(_value > 0 );
    if(isContract(_to)) {
        ERC223ReceivingContract receiver = ERC223ReceivingContract(_to);
        receiver.tokenFallback(msg.sender, _value, _data);
    }
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value, _data);
}
```

(Refer to https://gist.github.com/anonymous/eb7be71f34911b013552960cc4ac0f45)

This is the `ERC223 Token transfer function` and the `ERC223ReceivingContract` is imported `import 'browser/ERC223ReceivingContract.sol';` like this. I don't want to import the Contract because for the case when I have to update my Contract later. I want to remain my Token contract has only a few required functions.

I also found another function called `TransferAndCall()`. I can't find the detailed explanation how to use it. It seems like similar to Fallback function.

Anyway, do you guys have any solution to do this? Why I want to divide the "Trade" Smart Contract and "Token" Smart Contract is because for the case when I have to update my "Trade" Contract later like I mentioned. 
Please help me smart solidity experts!

Answer (score 0):

> After the "Trade" Smart Contract received the token, Token Fallback Function in "Trade" Smart Contract is called and executed the "Sell" function in that Contract.

**Yes.**

As you can see, in the `transfer` function, if the receiver is a contract, then it must have the a fallback function for the token, otherwise it won't work.

You need to implement this function in your contract.

```
if(isContract(_to)) {
        ERC223ReceivingContract receiver = ERC223ReceivingContract(_to);
        receiver.tokenFallback(msg.sender, _value, _data);
    }
```

As you can see, based on the abstract contract `ERC223ReceivingContract`, the signature of the function must be :

```
function tokenFallback(address _from, uint _value, bytes _data) public
```

Comment: This will throw if the contract is not an ERC223ReceivingContract, I don't think its okay to assume that all contracts interacting with this will be a ERC223ReceivingContract